# How to Reset the ColorFilter of a RemoteView in an AppWidget

Tags: android, android-appwidget

I am setting a ColorFilter on one of my ImageViews with the following code: -

```
views.setInt(myView, "setColorFilter", myColour);
```

Is there any way to remove this filter to return the colours to normal?  I have tried using: -

```
views.setInt(iconResource, "setColorFilter", -1);
```

Any ideas what I could do to reset this?
Thanks!

Comment: Setting the ColorFilter to 0 will clear the filter.

views.setInt(iconResource, "setColorFilter", 0);

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Setting the ColorFilter to 0 will clear the filter.

```
 views.setInt(iconResource, "setColorFilter", 0);
```

Comment: How to set colorFilter mode(PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY) on imageview in app widget? I couldn't find any.